# How to I change the order of my columns so it doesn't break an import with pg_restore

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pg-dump, datagrip

I'm trying to export data from a live Postgres DB into a local Postgres DB and have used `pg_dump` (via DataGrip) to dump the database into a tar file. I am using the INSERT option from the DataGrip dialogue which is giving the following.

```
--dbname="XXX" --format=t --file="XXX/DataGrip Backup/{timestamp}" --inserts
```

When I try and import the tar file using `pg_restore` (once again through DataGrip), one of my tables (the most important one!) won't import.

The error I'm getting is:

> pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "AUD"

The table has a numeric field and a varchar field. One for the discount and one for the currency being used.

This is from a model (Django) using the MoneyField:

```
coupon_discount = MoneyField(
    decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, default_currency="AUD", default=0.00
)
```

An example of the data I am importing is:

```
Command was: INSERT INTO public.customers_customer VALUES (2557, '', NULL, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2022-08-14 08:45:50.466306+00', '2022-08-14 08:45:50.466454+00', '2022-08-14 08:45:50.466459+00', 2559, '90h0nbJgDU', 0, 0.00, 'AUD', false, false, NULL, 1);
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "AUD"
LINE 1: ...10:31:35.347403+00', 2560, 'o4VxTmqlOa', 0, 0.00, 'AUD', fal...
```

When I look at the external Postgres DB the order of the two fields in the table is:

[image]

I assume this is the order the fields are given in the tar field. But when I check the local DB the order is different:

[image]

I don't think I've done anything to have it this way as Django is creating the tables and hence I assume the order?

Is there a way I can change this to have the data imported?

Do I need to export the data in a different way? I really just want the actual data to be imported. I already seem to have to use the `--ignore-triggers` somewhere to stop a whole host of problems with migration tables and others.

Comment: Table definitions are better shared as `CREATE TABLE` statements using [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `--column-inserts` (instead of `--inserts`) for pg_dump.

That will generate INSERT statements that will qualify the target columns.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realise that was an option. Now all I need to know is how to exclude tables (more than one at a time). I know there is an `--exclude-table-data` option but trying to work out how to exclude two or three tables.

Comment: `--exclude-table=` see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html